# How to write UT cases for mailto functionality in Jasmine?

Tags: jasmine, karma-jasmine

I need to write the UT cases for the following function

```
var emailsender=function(email)

    var link = "mailto:"+ email;

    window.location.href = link;

}
```

Can anyone give idea on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of testing function you provide, you better separate part which generate link with another function which could be easily testable. For example:

```
var emailsender = function (email) {
    var link = generateLink(email);
    window.location.href = link;
}

function generateLink(email) {
    return "mailto:"+ email;
}
```

And you would be able unit test the function which actually generates the link. Testing part which assign `window.location.href` is pointless, since this is means you just testing the browser.

Comment: Actually when  I am trying to Unit test the function that generates link, it is opening the default mail sender each time.